# Find the mass of the half circle

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the mass of the half circle that is defined by $x^{2} + y^{2} \le 4$ $(y \le 0)$ if the density at point $(x,y)$ is proportional to its squared distance from the point $(0, -2)$ and the density at point $(-2,0)$ is equal to $4\frac{g}{cm^{2}}$.

I do not understand where the fact that the density at point $(-2,0)$ is equal to $4\frac{g}{cm^{2}}$ belongs in all of this.

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be "...is **proportional** to its distance squared from the point..."? Then the density at $(-2,0)$ can be used to compute the constant of proportionality. This gives $\rho(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + (y+2)^2}{2}~g\text{cm}^{-2}$.

Comment: @Kibble Yes, it is supposed to be proportional. However, I am not exactly sure how you got $\rho(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + (y+2)^2}{2}~g\text{cm}^{-2}$. Could you exlain that?

Comment: We have $\rho(x,y) = kd(x,y)^2$ where $d(x,y)^2 = x^2 + (y+2)^2$ is the squaredistance from the point $(0,-2)$. Now plug in $(x,y) = (-2,0)$ where $\rho = 4$ and solve for $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult this figure, where the graylevel, representing the physical density, is proportional to the squared distance from $(0,-2)$:

[image]

Following @Kibble, we have the density at $(-2,0)$ is $4$, which gives the constant of proportionality $k$.

Then the total mass is:

$M = \int\limits_{r=0}^2 dr \int\limits_{\theta = \pi}^{2 \pi} r \rho(r, \theta) d\theta$

and $r$ is the distance from the origin and the unit of area is $dA = r\ dr\ d\theta$.

Now for the geometry:

[image]

Then use the law of cosines:

$d^2 = 2^2 - r^2 - 2\cdot 2 r \cos (\pi/2 - \theta)$.

Hence:

$M = \int\limits_{r = 0}^2 dr \int\limits_{\theta = \pi}^{2 \pi} r k (2^2 - r^2 - 4 r \cos (\pi/2 - \theta)) d \theta = {4 k \over 3} (16 + 3 \pi)$ and substitute $k$ from @Kibble's comment.

Comment: Assume $\theta = 0$ is along the positive $x$ axis.  In that case, $\pi \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$.

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. However, I do not understand why  $d^2 = 2^2 - r^2 - 2\cdot 2 r \cos (\pi/2 - \theta)$. I though that as $x=r \cos (\theta)$ and $y=r \sin (\theta)$, I would plug them into $d(x,y)^{2}$ and get $d(r,\theta)^{2} = r^{2} + 4r\sin(\theta) + 4$.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I would do as well to get $$\begin{align}\int_0^2\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac12(r^2+4r\sin\theta+4)d\theta\,r\,d&r=\frac12\left(\frac{\pi}4\cdot2^4-\frac83\cdot2^3+2\pi\cdot2^2\right)\\&=6\pi-  \frac{32}3\end{align}$$